# Keep this as context of base object in properties of javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I am wondering what I need to do to maintain a type of (var self = this) coupling within sub properties of a java script object. For example, if I had the following object:

```
var t = {
    helpers: {
        getName: function(){
            //how do i preserve this or get the mbase object instance here...
            //so i can for example do the following:
            var self = this;//this is now helpers object, but how to get to base object?
            return self.nickName + "...";
        },
        getTime: function(){

        }
    },
    nickName: 'test'
}
```

From what I understand currently, the this reference when in a object, is directly passed down into a function if it is a property of an object. Since this scenario is two objects don, is it the base or the "helpers" object when I reference (var self = this) and if so, how do I reach the base object property such as "nickNam" within obj.helpers.getNickName()?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `t.nickName` should do

Comment: Wow, I was way over complicating this one. Thanks.